# How to draw a spherical shell?

Tags: c#, vector, geometry, drawing

I'm trying to arrange points in a spherical shell in C#. I have code to arrange a bunch of points (I'm doing finite element analysis) in a spherical pattern with radius of `double earthRadius`. I can't figure out how to do the same for a spherical shell [like the type pictured here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5CQ4.png). Ideas?

```
for (double x = -earthRadius; x < earthRadius; x += pointIncrement) //taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671385/sphere-drawing-in-java and slightly altered to make more efficient
        {
            for (double y = -earthRadius; y < earthRadius; y += pointIncrement)
            {
                for (double z = -earthRadius; z < earthRadius; z += pointIncrement)
                {
                    if ((x * x) + (y * y) + (z * z) <= earthRadius * earthRadius)
                    {
                        earth.AddPoint(new Vector(x, y, z), 0); 
                        totalPoints++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I suggest that you loop over [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) to find your points. After that convert them to cartesian coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out using just Cartesian coordinates. I elected not to use spherical coordinates because it was a suboptimal solution: it made the code less elegant and using `Math.Sin()` and `Math.Cos()` would have slowed it down. Here's the eventual solution I got:

```
  for (double x = -earthRadius; x < earthRadius; x += pointIncrement) //taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671385/sphere-drawing-in-java and slightly altered to make more efficient
        {
            for (double y = -earthRadius; y < earthRadius; y += pointIncrement)
            {
                for (double z = -earthRadius; z < earthRadius; z += pointIncrement)
                {
                    if ((x * x) + (y * y) + (z * z) <= earthRadius * earthRadius)
                    {

                        if ((x * x) + (y * y) + (z * z) >= (earthRadius - shellThickness) * (earthRadius - shellThickness))
                        {

                            earth.AddPoint(new Vector(x, y, z), 0); // need to figure out how to calculate masspoint
                            totalPoints++;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Notice that I simply added another if statement. I (foolishly) didn't use the && operator because I thought it reduced readability.